# Recursive Prime Number function c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand how to use recursive functions, and I do not understand why this function is wrong. I believe it is in Base Case 2, but I don't know why.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Returns 0 if value is not prime, 1 if value is prime
int IsPrime(int testVal, int divVal)
{
   // Base case 1: 0 and 1 are not prime, testVal is not prime
   if(testVal == 0 || testVal == 1){
      return 0;
   }
   // Base case 2: testVal only divisible by 1, testVal is prime
   if(testVal/1 == testVal){
      return 1;
   }
   // Recursive Case
      // Check if testVal can be evenly divided by divVal
      // Hint: use the % operator
      if(testVal % divVal != 1){
         IsPrime(testVal, divVal);
         }
      // If not, recursive call to isPrime with testVal and (divVal - 1)
   return 0;
}

int main(){
   int primeCheckVal = 0; // Value checked for prime

   // Check primes for values 1 to 10
   for (primeCheckVal = 1; primeCheckVal <= 10; ++primeCheckVal) {
      if (IsPrime(primeCheckVal, (primeCheckVal - 1)) == 1) {
         cout << primeCheckVal << " is prime." << endl;
      }
      else {
         cout << primeCheckVal << " is not prime." << endl;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to accomplish with `if(testVal/1 == testVal)` - it will **always** be true as everything divided by 1 will equal itself.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  Doing  that you would catch that ou never modify `testVal` or `divVal`

Answer (score 0):

`testVal/1 == testVal` is *always* true (provided you're not playing with weird things like infinities or NaNs) so probably doesn't do what you expect (checking if the number is *only* divisible by one) - try it with the prime `7` and the composite `15` and you'll see it's so.

Hence any number other than zero or one passed to your function will be erroneously detected as a prime.

To see if a number is only divisible by one, you need to check that it's not divisible by any other candidate value. By way of example (pseudo-code):

```
def isPrime(n):
    testVal = 2
    while testVal * testVal <= n:
        if int (n / testVal) * testVal == n:
            return false
    return true
```

---

As an aside, I'm not entirely convinced that primality tested is suited to a recursive solution. You may want to look at either a non-recursive solution (if your aim is to detect primes) or a different problem (if your aim is to learn recursion).